# Looping through dictionaries while creating new keys

Tags: python, loops, datetime, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one that contains city coordinates and another that contains a time slice. My data comes for a netcdf file which I open here.

```
data=xr.open_dataset('E:/Riskpulse_HD/Jon climate study/adaptor.mars.internal-1583855532.1432714-8122-5-ace27afd-90c0-4a7d-b9ca-f3d5528c5ea1.nc')
```

Then I set my variable.

```
lat = data['latitude'][:]
lon = data['longitude'][:]
temp = data['t2m'][:,0,:,:]-273

cities = {
    "Shangai": {"coords": [31.25, 121.5]},
    "Singapore": {"coords": [1.25, 103.75]},
    "Shenzhen": {"coords": [22.5, 114]},...}

decades = {
    "1990s": {"start": dt.datetime(1990,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(1999,12,31)},
    "2000s": {"start": dt.datetime(2000,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(2009,12,31)},
    "2010s": {"start": dt.datetime(2010,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(2019,12,31)}}
```

I want to loop through these and create new keys such that I could have something like `cities["Shangai"]["1990s"]`. Here is the code I use to attempt that:

```
for city, location in cities.items():
    data = temp.sel(latitude=location['coords'][0], longitude=location['coords'][0])
    for decade, dates in decades.items():
        city[decade] += data.sel(time=(slice(dates['start'], dates['end'])))
```

However, it returns this error and I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me.

**Error :**

```
*-->4 city[decade] += data.sel(time=(slice(dates['start'], dates['end'])))*

*TypeError: string indices must be integers*
```

**Edit**

I was able to solve this eventually.

```
for city, location in cities.items():
    data = temp.sel(latitude=location['coords'][0], longitude=location['coords'][0])
    for decade, dates in decades.items():
        cities[city][decade] = data.sel(time=(slice(dates['start'], dates['end'])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a `value` to a `dict[key]`. This is done via `dict[key] = value` (you wrote `+=`).

I don't know what your `temp.sel` and `data.sel` does but in your case you'd be fine with writing:

```
for city, citydata in cities.items():
  for decade, dates in decades.items():
    cities[city][decade] = dates
```

Comment: I edited my post to show you where those come from. The code you provided just populates a time slice with no data. How would I edit the loop to now include the data with the time slice?